# .NET - Custom Types Possible?

Tags: c#, vb.net, delphi, types

In Delphi you can do something like this :

```
TArray = array[1..3] of byte;
```

where you can then declare

```
T2Array = array[1..3] of TArray
```

ad nauseum...

Does something like this exist in .NET? (vb, c#, whatever)

I am currently doing something like this

```
Private LotsOfData As ObservableCollection(Of ObservableCollection(Of myClass))
```

but would like to do

```
Private LotsOfData As ObservableCollection(Of myType)
```

where

```
myType -->  ObservableCollection(Of myClass)
```

I know you can do this with structures, ie:

```
Public Structure MyType
     Public myOc as ObservableCollection(Of MyClass)
End Structure

Dim LotsOfData as ObservableCollection(of MyType)
```

but you then have to reference it as (for example)

```
LotsOfData.Last.myOc(i)
```

instead of

```
LotsOfData.Last(i)
```

which seems clumsy.  This also seems clumsy :

```
For Each Data as ObservableCollection(of myClass) in LotsOfData
     DoSomething(Data)
Next
```

as does

```
For Each Data as MyType in LotsOfData
     DoSomething(Data.myOc)
Next
```

when it could be

```
For Each Data as MyType in LotsOfData
     DoSomething(Data)
Next
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about defining custom classes that derive from the closed type of your generic collection? For example:

```
public class MyType : ObservableCollection<MyClass>
{ }
```

Then you could create another generic collection whose type parameter is your above-defined class (which is itself a collection):

```
ObservableCollection<MyType> lotsOfData = new ObservableCollection<MyType>();
```

When you iterate over it, you would get the sequence of inner collections:

```
foreach (ObservableCollection<MyClass> data in lotsOfData)
{
    DoSomething(data);
}
```

**Edit**: Deriving as shown above will allow you to inherit all accessible members from the base `ObservableCollection<T>` class, but you won’t be able to call its (non-default) constructors. Thus, you would typically want to implement the constructors with the same overloads as the base class:

```
public class MyType : ObservableCollection<MyClass>
{
    public MyType()
        : base()
    { }

    public MyType(IEnumerable<MyClass> collection)
        : base(collection)
    { }

    public MyType(List<MyClass> list)
        : base(list)
    { }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant.  I didn't know you could inherit a collection of a specific type.  This is exactly the solution.

Comment: Also, you can go the final step and say `foreach(MyType data in lotsOfData) {DoSomething(data)}`  which is what I really wanted.

Comment: Yes. Whichever declared type you choose, you can then always perform an inner `foreach (MyClass item in data)`.

Comment: Derivation should only be used to customize behavior. Here you are only doing it to provide a name alias. This is not a good reason for inheritance.

Comment: We don’t know what else the OP is doing with the class; the code is only an example. If they don’t need to use it other than as an alias, then I would recommend scrapping the whole idea altogether, stay with nested generics, and then use `var` to simplify variable declarations.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to create a type alias in the code.  VB.Net does have support for that in the form of the `Imports` directive

```
Imports myType = System.Collections.Generic.ObservableCollection(Of myClass)

...

Private LotsOfData As ObservableCollection(Of myType)
```

Note the `Imports` directive must be repeated for every file in which you want to use `myType`.

Comment: How about inheritance? Is there any reason `myType` can't just derive from `ObservableCollection<myClass>`?

Comment: @Gabe you can but I wouldn't.  `ObservableCollection<T>`, while unsealed, isn't meant to be inherited from.  Inheriting from it provides no value other than a name alias.  It's only unsealed because the BCL team for some reason won't seal types htat need to be sealed

Comment: @Gabe, if you have code elsewhere that returns type `ObservableCollection<myClass>`, you can't assign it to a variable of type `myType`.

Comment: @RobKennedy so you would prefer adding the `Imports` directive as needed rather than exposing a public class which inherits from `ObservableCollection<X>`?  Primary reasons?

Comment: @JaredPar: I agree that a type alias may be an equal or superior solution in this scenario, but I don’t agree that `ObservableCollection<T>` should be sealed. There are plenty of cases where you might need to extend its behaviour – for example, to support concurrency.

Comment: @Douglas trying to inject concurrency into a type which is not designed for concurrency by deriving is very unlikely to succeed.

Comment: I never said what I'd prefer, @J...; I'm pointing out a shortcoming of the "derived type" solution. It's not a true type alias. *Everything* needs to cooperate by using the derived type name. Code that wasn't written with the new name won't work with new code because it will be providing instances of the base class, not the derived class, even though there's really nothing different between them. VB supports file-local type aliases. C# apparently doesn't. Oxygene supports public type aliases. You assumed you were asking for a .Net feature, but it's not; languages vary in how they name types.

Comment: @JaredPar: I wouldn’t generally agree (assuming you don’t need the _best_ performance). But concurrency on `ObservableCollection<T>` was a bad example for me to pick due to issues arising from the `CollectionChanged` events being raised on the “wrong” threads.

Comment: @RobKennedy so C# `using myType = System.Collections...(etc)` would not work?  Interesting.  I mean, I know that IL is exposed to varying degrees by different languages - I suppose I should have been more precise.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @RobKennedy: I believe C# supports it too.
`using myType = System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<myClass>;`

Comment: Thanks, @Douglas. I was assuming it wasn't possible because of the lack of answers mentioning it. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: @J...: Accept whichever answer convinces you enough to adopt it in your code. If you only need the “new” type for simplifying the name of the generic collection, then type aliasing is probably the better approach. If you think that you might want to introduce custom functionality in your `myType` class, then use inheritance.

Comment: @Douglas - I suppose what I mean is that both approaches have their merits and were both enlightening, not specifically for the case at hand but in general and for potential use in the future.  I may well end up using both of these ideas in different places at different times.

Comment: @J...: That sounds like the best approach. In my case, I usually don’t use type aliasing since I stick to nested generics (e.g. `ICollection<ICollection<MyClass>>`) when I don’t need to introduce custom functionality, but that’s a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

You can define type aliases in Oxygene, the .Net Delphi language. Same syntax as classic Delphi.

```
type
  MyType = ObservableCollection<MyClass>;
```

You can use `public` to make the name visible in other assemblies.

Comment: Not sure why this got a downmod but +1 from me.  I haven't played with Oxygene yet but I'm sure we will cross paths at some point.  The notion of Delphi + .NET has a certain appeal.

Answer (score 1):

Start with IEnumerable where T is the type you are operating on.  There are many implementations including `List<T>` which allows you to easily sort, push and pop elements.

For example...

```
var myListOfThings = new List<Thing>(); 
myListOfThings.Add(new Thing {Name = "Green thing" }); 
myListOfThings.Add(new Thing { Name = "Red thing" }); 
myListOfThings.Add(new Thing { Name = "Yellow thing" });
```

And when using IEnumerable you get access to [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query)...

```
var redThing = myListOfThings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Red Thing");
```

And easy iteration...

```
foreach(var thing in myListOfThings)
{
     // do something
}
```

NOTE: I don't have any VB examples, but you tagged the question with C#, so I hope these are useful.

Comment: The code I'm working on is VB so it was faster to type it out in VB - tagged as C# because it's all the same thing (more or less) and it all makes as much sense.  Thanks for the answer!